# Is there any significance to the title screen in The Last Of Us?

Tags: the-last-of-us

Is there any significance to the title screen in The Last Of Us? Is it a location that you ever encounter in the game? I don't remember seeing it.

I know that it changes subtly after beating the game, when Ellie's switchblade appears on the window sill. This makes me think that the window sill might be in the place where the surviving character(s) are heading at the game's conclusion.

Comment: (I tried to word the question in a way that would not require use of the spoiler tag...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is any significance, it's left unstated, and open to the interpretation of the player.

> It's possible that it's a location in the Jackson County town that Tommy and his group were working on fortifying, implying that Ellie has found a home there, and no reason to continue to carry her switchblade.